# Sonata admin delete confirmation with pop-up window

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I know the classic Admin page has confirmation for deleting and modifying information, but that confirmation is another page. Can you set that confirmation page to be displayed as a pop-up window instead of another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with javascript. You can use bootbox library.
http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html

Html:

```
<a href="#" data-href="id/delete">Delete</a>
```

In javascript, create listener for delete button:

```
$("a.confirm-delete").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $link = $(this);

    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result == true) {
            document.location.assign($link.attr('data-href'));
        }
    });
});
```

In your controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/delete", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
 */
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Product $p)
{
    $this->em->remove($p);
    $this->em->flush();

    return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('route'));
}
```